# How to select hard to see faces in edit mode?

Tags: selection-tools

This model has lots of faces htat are hard to see. Is there any way to select all connected faces of a selected face? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: maybe the faces are not connected? or there's a problem with your shortcut?

Comment: If they are not connected and they should be, you can try to merge by distance, if they are connected than ctrl and "+" should select all faces that are connected, you just need to hold it long enough

Answer (score 2):

Normally, in edit-mode you can select connected faces via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num +</kbd>. This is called *growing selection* and works for vertices and edges as well. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd> you can shrink your selection accordingly.

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does not work, growing selection will not work either, since your faces clearly are not connected. Maybe you ripped them accidentally. Try selecting all vertices, hit <kbd>M</kbd> for *Merge*, and click *By Distance*. This should meld all faces together again.